# Assertion failure in -UIPickerTableView

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

*** Assertion failure in -[UIPickerTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:9269

Application crashes because of this error. Please someone help.

Comment: I have tried all the solutions which were mentioned in the earlier post. Need a different solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar Problem and Solution

**Issue**: Application had UIDatePicker as input view for 3 or more UITextFields. Setting Date to first text field worked fine. App crashed when I tried 
 `datePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: true)`

Solution: I created distinct UIDatePickers for each textfield which solved my issue.

The below reference has few other solutions for similar scenarios:
[Assertion failure in -[UIPickerTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:7768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155082/assertion-failure-in-uipickertableview-createpreparedcellforglobalrowwithind?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue, please check that there is enough space for displaying PickerView. If given constraints try to solve the constraints conflict.